# Can Salesforce Shield Encryption encrypt data IN TRANSIT (or only at rest)?

Tags: salesforce

Could you please confirm?

Is Salesforce Shield Encryption solution encrypting data at rest **only**? OR... does it also encrypt the data IN TRANSIT?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_overview.htm) states:

> Shield Platform Encryption gives your data a whole new layer of security while preserving critical platform functionality. It enables you to **encrypt sensitive data at rest, and not just when transmitted over a network**, so your company can confidently comply with privacy policies, regulatory requirements, and contractual obligations for handling private data.

Emphasis mine. Data is already encrypted when transmitted over secure HTTPS connections, which of course does not require Shield.